# C2248: Cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, class, private, member

We are trying to compile an application using VS2005 and we are receiving the following error message:

error C2248: 'palo::bytecode_generator::WM_OPCODES' : cannot access private enum declared in class 'palo::bytecode_generator'   c:\users\administrator\desktop\htbase\development\palo_server_988\server_export\source\library\virtualmachine\VirtualMachine.h  199

This is the piece of code:

```
struct machine_state {
    EPath path;
    ERule* rule;
    Value defValue;
    Status defStatus;
    uint8_t is_base;
    Bytecode * pc;
    Value* sp_dbl;
    string* sp_str;
    bytecode_generator::WM_OPCODES return_pos;
};
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously the `WM_OPCODE` enum type is defined inside private section of `bytecode_generator`. Move it to public section or outside the class.

Comment: If `WM_OPCODES` is `private`, it's probably not meant to be used.

Comment: ...or it shouldn't be private. That's for OP to decide